# Cancel a task without checking for cancellation token in a loop

Tags: c#, task

Lets stay we have the following code:

```
Var task = Task.Run(() => RunTest(ct.Token));

Void RunTask(CancellationToken token)
{
If (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
}

 Cmd.CommandText = code;
 Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
```

This does now cancel a long running SQL query which is running, how can I immediately kill the task if Cancellation is requested and terminate the long running SQL query? I know about the 'Cancel()' but how can I trigger it based on the cancellationToken?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop SQL query execution from .net Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779679/stop-sql-query-execution-from-net-code)

Answer (score 3):

If you use `ExecuteNonQuery` then the thread that your task is running on is waiting somewhere in someone else's code - it's not available for you to commandeer and do other work with.

But the good news is, you don't need it to be. Just use [`ExecuteNonQueryAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204860(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and let the `SqlCommand` object handle cancellation itself.

```
async Task RunTask(CancellationToken token)
{
  Cmd.CommandText = code;
  await Cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(token);
}
```

You may also want to [`Unwrap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780917(v=vs.110).aspx) what's in your `task` variable at this stage, since it's now a `Task<Task>` and usually, if you're interested at all, you'd be interested in when the inner `Task` is complete.

Or you may want to consider whether `Task.Run` is required at all. That depends on why the `Task.Run` was inserted into your sample in the first case and on how much actual activity `RunTask` is performing.

Answer (score 0):

To cancel a `SqlCommand` you should use `SqlCommand.Cancel()` method

take a look here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel.aspx

Comment: I know about the 'Cancel()' but how can I trigger it based on the cancellationToken?

Comment: This post can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738417/canceling-sql-server-query-with-cancellationtoken