# C# : Cancelling MySqlCommand using CancellationToken giving NULLReferenceException

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mysqlcommand

I was trying to cancel a `MySqlCommand` using a `CancellationToken`. The query executes successfully when cancellation is not requested.

```
public async Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(string connectionString, string query, 
       CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    int affectedRowsCount = 0;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Connection = connection;
                cancellationToken.Register(() => command.Cancel());

                command.CommandText = query;
                command.CommandTimeout = 0;

                affectedRowsCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
             }
         }
     });

     return affectedRowsCount;
}
```

But when cancellation is requested it is producing NullReferenceException.
Can't figure out what is NULL.

[image]

I am calling the above method by

```
deletedRowsInLastIteration = await 
    mySqlHelperService.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(
       connectionString,
       query, 
       cancellationToken);
```

if I try

```
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

before calling the `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` method, it works. But the cancel of MySqlCommand is not working.

This is the stack trace

> System.NullReferenceException   HResult=0x80004003   Message=Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.   Source=MySql.Data
>   StackTrace:    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CancelQuery(Int32 timeout)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Cancel()    at
>   ProjectName.Common.MySqlHelperService.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.b__1()
>   in
>   C:\Users\username\source\repos\ProjectName\Applications\ProjectName.Common\MySqlHelperService.cs:line
>   55    at
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken.ActionToActionObjShunt(Object obj) 
>   at
>   System.Threading.CancellationCallbackInfo.ExecutionContextCallback(Object
>   obj)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.CancellationCallbackInfo.ExecuteCallback()    at
>   System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.CancellationCallbackCoreWork(CancellationCallbackCoreWorkArguments
>   args)    at
>   System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ExecuteCallbackHandlers(Boolean
>   throwOnFirstException)

Comment: Check that `cancellationToken` has been initialized.

Comment: Yes CancellationToken is initialised

Comment: How and where did you initialize it?

Comment: I am passing it to this method. I will update the code

Comment: Post the full exception text, not just a screenshot of the message. Click on `Copy Details` and paste the text in the question itself. That text contains the stack trace that shows *where* the NRE was thrown and what method were involved. It could be that the command is disposed by the time the cancellation occurs. Or it could be that there's yet another bug in Connector/Net's implementation of MySqlCommand

Comment: Why don't you use `ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken)` though? Why waste a thread with Task.Run and hack cancellation like this?

Comment: This is probably failing because the cancellation token registration (set up by `cancellationToken.Register(() => command.Cancel());`) is never deregistered, so it might try to cancel the command long after it's been disposed.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger But this is working fine with SqlCommand. Dont know what's the problem with MySqlCommand

Comment: The problem with MySqlCommand is that it comes from the MySql.Data package, which has a large number of outstanding known bugs. I strongly recommend switching to MySqlConnector, to get all these bug fixes: https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Task.Run` to convert synchronous methods to asynchronous ones. At best, this wastes a thread just waiting for some IO operation to complete.

`MySqlCommand` has an `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` method that accepts a cancellation token. `MySqlConnection` itself has an `OpenAsync` method. You should change your code to :

```
public async Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(string connectionString, string query, 
       CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query,connection))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;

            var affectedRowsCount = await command.ExecuteNonQuery(cancellationToken);
         }
    }

    return affectedRowsCount;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I will try this out and let you know +1

Comment: This won't cancel the query if you're using MySQL Connector/NET (aka MySql.Data) since it doesn't support async methods: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111
Switch to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ instead, which has full async I/O support.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger looking at the code - it's worse than I remember, if that's possible. BeginXXX ends up starting a new thread but the Async methods *fake* it? They don't even try to use BeginXXX? And CancelQuery doesn't cancel the query. It tries to issue a `KILL QUERY` on another connection

Comment: @jophab it looks like it doesn't work after all. MySQL fakes async execution and the method runs *synchronously*. Even cancellation is faked. `Cancel` executes a `KILL QUERY` on a *new* connection. I keep forgetting just how bad Connector/NET is.  You shouldn't use it if possible. If you want real async execution use the MySqlConnector  package. Which, btw, doesn't have *sync* methods, and fakes them by blocking on the async methods

Comment: Yeah I will try it out

Comment: "Which, btw, doesn't have sync methods, and fakes them by blocking on the async methods" @PanagiotisKanavos This is not true. The sync methods are truly sync all the way down to the Socket level. Calling `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on a synchronously-completed task is not "blocking on async". Source: I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating your cancellation Token and what is his value?

Also here is a solution how to cancel a sql command with a cancellation token

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts;
private async void TestSqlServerCancelSprocExecution()
{
cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connStr"))
        {
            conn.InfoMessage += conn_InfoMessage;
            conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
            conn.Open();

            var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cts.Token.Register(() => cmd.Cancel());
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.[CancelSprocTest]";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
   });
}
catch (SqlException)
{
    // sproc was cancelled
}
```

}

[The code above is from this question, which had kinda the same problem, that the cancellation token won't cancel the sql command.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738417/canceling-sql-server-query-with-cancellationtoken)

Comment: Cancellation is working fine with SqlCommand. My problem is with MySqlCommand